# Recently viewed products not showing old price for the Configurable product in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, recently-viewed

[image]

> please anyone suggest me how to do this?

Comment: please clear explain your question

Comment: Recently viewed products not getting regular price of configurable product but it's working for simple products. How to configure it?